# Alexa does not always understand a custom invocation name

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I created an Alexa Skill, but Alexa does not always understand the invocation name so the skill won't fire. Some users run into this problem very frequently, while others do not.

The invocation name is a one-word (multi-syllable) company name and serves as the brand identity.

Is there a way to train Alexa to better understand custom invocation names?

Answer (score 1):

Alexa invocation names should be as simple as possible to easily invoke a custom skill. AI engines are well trained primarily on dictionary words,famous names, etc although they will work on any new word too. But AI engines improve as per their training, which means how well the engine is trained to understand a word. This depends on different voice data existing in an engine for a single word.

Few engines support and allow to train it, which means you can try to train the engine on new words or the words it struggle with. But it is not an easy thing to do either. Unfortunately there is no way that you can train the Alexa AI engine as a skill developer.

As a suggestion, you should find a better invocation name, that can easily be pronounced with different accents.

Answer (score 0):

Invocation name of Alexa SKill should be something that a user can easily remember and is self explanatory for the skill. It should not be more than 2 3 words and easy to remember. 
Do refer to best practices given on Invocation name screen in ASK.